A VHS of animated children's poetry
When I was a kid I used to rent this video of short animated films based on children's poetry and nursery rhymes. The ones I can remember being included were "The Owl And The Pussycat", "Mr. Nobody", and "The Duel" ('The gingham dog and the calico cat, Side by side on the table sat…')
Between each short was, for some reason, animated POV shots of someone driving their car at different times of the day. You saw their hands on the steering wheel, the dashboard, and the view out the windshield.
If anyone knows what I'm talking about and the title of the VHS, that would be so cool. Thanks!

I don't know if this has the steering wheel montages in the video, but the video "Nonsense and Lullabies: Poems" is animated and has all of the poems that you listed. A listing of the poems contained in the video is available at this link, and are as follows:

Creature in the classroom --
  Homework --
  Bugs in the night --
  The story of Augustus who would not eat his soup --
  Matilda --
  Mr. Nobody --
  The bogeyman --
  Autumn fires --
  The owl and the pussycat --
  The tin frog --
  Wrimples --
  Windy nights --
  The duel --
  Jigsaw puzzle


That's it! And now I remember the cover with a big black monster on it! Thanks. :D
